# Remove cloud build trigger from github checks

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I had a cloud build trigger that would run tests on pull request.
Then I disabled the trigger and then deleted it. But it still shows up in Github PR. How can I remove it?

[image: Github Pr screen shot]

Comment: Did you remove the outdated check in the protected branch settings of the repository settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting the trigger from Cloud Build, I also had to remove it from Github repository settings:
[image]